# Strip All Foreign-Namespace Nodes with XQuery

Tags: xquery

Input document:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>urn:uuid:1234</id>
    <updated>2012-01-20T11:30:11-05:00</updated>
    <published>2011-12-29T15:44:11-05:00</published>
    <link href="?id=urn:uuid:1234" rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <category scheme="http://uri/categories" term="category"/>
    <fake:fake xmlns:fake="http://fake/" attr="val"/>
    <content type="xhtml">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>Blah</p>
        </div>
    </content>
</entry>
<!-- more entries -->
```

I want the output to be exactly the same, but with non-Atom elements like `<fake:fake xmlns:fake="http://fake/" attr="val"/>` stripped out. This is what I have, which doesn't work at all, just giving me the same input back:

```
declare namespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
<feed>
<title>All Posts</title>
{
for $e in collection('/db/entries')/atom:entry
return
    if
        (namespace-uri($e) = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    then
        $e
    else
        ''
}
</feed>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of a round-about way of doing it but this ended up working:

```
declare default element namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
<feed>
<title>All Posts</title>
{
for $entry in collection('/db/entries')/entry
return
    element{node-name($entry)}{
        $entry/@*,
        for $child in $entry//*[namespace-uri(.) = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"]
        return $child
    }
}
</feed>
```

Waiting for the time limit to expire and then I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: That's good too if you are sure that your foreign elements are always direct children of the entry element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query on [try.zorba-xquery.com](http://try.zorba-xquery.com):

```
let $entry := <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>urn:uuid:1234</id>
    <updated>2012-01-20T11:30:11-05:00</updated>
    <published>2011-12-29T15:44:11-05:00</published>
    <link href="?id=urn:uuid:1234" rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <category scheme="http://uri/categories" term="category"/>
    <fake:fake xmlns:fake="http://fake/" attr="val"/>
    <content type="xhtml">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>Blah</p>
        </div>
    </content>
</entry>
return {
  delete nodes $entry//*[not(namespace-uri(.) = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")];
  $entry
}
```

The following version is more portable:

```
let $entry := <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>urn:uuid:1234</id>
    <updated>2012-01-20T11:30:11-05:00</updated>
    <published>2011-12-29T15:44:11-05:00</published>
    <link href="?id=urn:uuid:1234" rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <category scheme="http://uri/categories" term="category"/>
    <fake:fake xmlns:fake="http://fake/" attr="val"/>
    <content type="xhtml">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>Blah</p>
        </div>
    </content>
</entry>
return
  copy $new-entry := $entry
  modify (delete nodes $new-entry//*[not(namespace-uri(.) = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")])
  return $new-entry
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do this when the input is a collection rather than embedded directly? I am trying to transform results from eXist and these examples don't seem to be working for that.

Comment: Nevermind, solved it. Your examples steered me in the right direction though! +1.